# Changing Integral Bounds By Making Variable Negative in MGF Proof

Tags: real-analysis, indefinite-integrals, moment-generating-functions

As part of a proof for Moment Generating Functions being symmetric about 0 for even probability density functions, I see the following line in my textbook:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{\epsilon x} f_X(x) dx + \int_0^{\infty} e^{\epsilon x} f_X(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\epsilon x} f_X(-x) dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-\epsilon x} f_X(-x) dx$$

I am pretty familiar with integrals changing signs when flipping boundaries, but have not seen the above before. What is the justification for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just elementary (Calculus 1) change of variables, e.g. for the first integral let $u=-x$, so (informally) $du=-dx$ and the limits of integration now go from $\infty$ to $0$, hence:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{0} \exp(\varepsilon x) f_X(x) dx = \int_{\infty}^0 -\exp(-\varepsilon u) f_X(-u)du = \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-\varepsilon u) f_X(-u) du
$$

Note that the 1st equality here is just the change of variables, and the second one is the "changing signs when flipping boundaries" which you mention.